# Do something then append that value do an empty vector

Tags: r, statistics, data-science

I have written a function that draws random variates from a normal distribution with outliers. However I now want to take the mean of this data and append it to an empty vector 1000 times (so essentially a vector with 1000 different means using my function) Here is my attempt so so far.

```
M = 1000
for (i in 1:M){
  means = numeric()
  m = mean(rnormout(100,0,1,0,10))
  means[i] = m[i]
}
```

However I just seem to get 1000 NAs in my means vector, any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this. If you want to use a loop, the trick is to define an empty vector before initiating the loop, and store values in that. Here's an example using `rnorm` to generate values from a standard normal, since I don't have the code for your `rnormout` function:

```
M <- 1000
means <- vector()
for (i in 1:M){
  means[i] = mean(rnorm(100, 0, 1))
}
```

Alternatively, it's better not to use a for loop at all. You can use `map_dbl` to replace the loop in one line:

```
library(tidyverse)
M <- 1000
means <- map_dbl(1:M, ~ mean(rnorm(100, 0, 1)))
```

Comment: Thank you! Initiating the empty vector outside makes sense as the loop would keep creating and empty vector over and over...

Answer (score 0):

We could use `sapply` in `base R` (use `R 4.1.0`)

```
M <- 1000
sapply(seq_len(M), \(x) mean(rnorm(100, 0, 1)))
```